# Decrypt AES-128 CBC - PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I have an encrypted message in AES-128 CBC in this format "f21fcc6677c9ba2335da551fa143cf08" and I'm trying to decrypt using a key in this format "cdff8db86efb418a8e492a29dba44869", I'm new to this and I can't seem to make it work, I tried this code with no success.

```
<?php

$simple_string = base64_decode('f21fcc6677c9ba2335da551fa143cf08');
echo $simple_string. "\n";
//echo $simple_string;


$ciphering = 'AES-128-CBC';

$iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
$options   = 0;


$encryption_key = 'cdff8db86efb418a8e492a29dba44869';
echo $encryption_key. "\n";

$decryption = openssl_decrypt($simple_string, $ciphering, $encryption_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);

var_dump($decryption);
```

my output is

```
bool(false)
```

any ideas? I think I have to change the format of the encrypted message or the key, but don't find much in Google.

Comment: You aren't using your `$iv_length` or `$options` variables anywhere. You may want to double-check the encryption spec from your source, and then make sure that your [openssl_decrypt](https://www.php.net/openssl_decrypt) applies all of that, incl. whether things are in binary or hex.

Comment: I read that IV is not necessary in cbc, I tried it either way and same result, I just left it there when I was testing, I tried with base64 encode and decode and hex2bin and nothing

Comment: I'm going to check but the API documentation says I have to decrypt with AES-128 CBC

Comment: Key and ciphertext seem to be hex encoded, if so they must be hex decoded (`hex2bin()`). PHP/openssl uses a zero vector in CBC mode if the IV is not explicitly specified (btw, CBC applies an IV by definition). Is the plaintext or at least the plaintext length known? Maybe no padding was used during encryption (PHP/openssl applies PKCS#7 padding by default).

Comment: There is only one block of ciphertext, which means that either the IV is missing or we should assume it is zero. In that case you are just left with AES decrypt. The result of that calculation (without unpadding) is `e3f8c25e440442bceba6de4f35599c23`, see [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Decrypt(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'cdff8db86efb418a8e492a29dba44869'%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':'00000000000000000000000000000000'%7D,'CBC/NoPadding','Hex','Hex',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)&input=ZjIxZmNjNjY3N2M5YmEyMzM1ZGE1NTFmYTE0M2NmMDg)...

Comment: Obviously, the idea that CBC doesn't use an IV is demonstrably wrong, just look up CBC in block cipher modes of operation on Wikipedia. All non-deterministic ciphers need to be randomized, so the IV is really a requirement for block cipher modes of operation.